# To keep the width of box constant irrespective of the length of text

Tags: html, css, forms

I am working on a timeline tool. The problem I am facing here is that when I select next or previous, according to the length of date, it's position changes. I don't want that with the change in date, position of the timeline tool changes.

```css
.timelinetool {
 background: rgba(108, 171, 231, 0.3);
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 2px auto 2px auto;
 padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 28;
 -moz-border-radius: 28;
 border-radius: 28px;

}

.btn1 {
 border-width: 0px;
 background: #3498db;
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
 -webkit-border-radius: 28;
 -moz-border-radius: 28;
 border-radius: 28px;
 font-family: Arial;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-size: 15px;
 padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
 width: 120px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
 .textBetween {
 width:250px;
    margin: auto; 
    background-size: 250px;
    border-width: 0px;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
 
} 

.btn {
 border-width: 0px;
 float: center;
 background: #3498db;
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
 -webkit-border-radius: 28;
 -moz-border-radius: 28;
 border-radius: 28px;
 font-family: Arial;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-size: 15px;
 padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
 z-index: 2;
 cursor: pointer;
    width: 280px;
}

.btn:hover,.btn1:hover {
 background: #3cb0fd;
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<h:form>
    <div style="margin-left: 10%;" class="timelinetool">
     <h:commandButton value="Previous" title="Go to previous week"
                class="btn1" action="#{trafficDisplayPagination.preval}">
      <f:ajax render="foo" />
  </h:commandButton>
  <h:panelGroup id="foo">
      <span class="textBetween">
                <h:outputText value="#{trafficDisplayPagination.previousWeekLink}" />
   </span>
   <h:commandButton 
                    value="#{trafficDisplayPagination.currentWeekLink} "
     title="Click to load Initiatives of this week" 
                    class="btn" 
                    action="#{trafficDisplayPagination.OnClickofDate}">
       <f:ajax render=":form:datatablediv" />
   </h:commandButton>

   <span class="textBetween"> 
                <h:outputText value="#{trafficDisplayPagination.nextWeekLink}" />
   </span>
  </h:panelGroup>

  <h:commandButton value="Next" title="Go to next week"
          class="btn1" 
                         action="#{trafficDisplayPagination.nextval}">
   <f:ajax render="foo" />
  </h:commandButton>
 </div>
</h:form>
```

Comment: use max-width:Xpx!important and position:absolute

Comment: @RachelGallen - Not working..!!

Comment: can't reproduce your problem in a fiddle cos it's asp